# converting python hangman to GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests, subprocess

I am working with our project on creating guessing word. but I am having a problem regarding with loops and letters that should be added on the `labelGuessResult`. please help me to resolve my codes and help me to understand what's the problem to my codes. the result I would like to get are the correct guessed letters are showing in `labelGuessResult` and everytime I enter a correct guess it will add like this s `_ren`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from random import choice
randomWords = choice(["yeti", "siren", "lich"])
lives = 7
guessedWord = []
guessedWrong = []

#defining the main class
class window(Frame):
#defining main window initialization
def __init__(self, master=None):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()

#defining main frame
def init_window(self):

    self.master.title("H A N G M A N")
    self.master.resizable(False, False)
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    self.label1 = Label(self, text="Guessed the %s letter word: " % (len(randomWords)))
    self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky=W)

    '''DISPLAY WORD'''
    self.labelGuessResult = Label(self, text=len(randomWords)* " _")
    self.labelGuessResult.grid(row=1, column=2)

    '''GUESS INPUT'''
    self.guessEnt = Entry(self)
    self.guessEnt.grid(row=1, column=3)
    guess = self.guessEnt.get()


    self.label2 = Label(self, text="Message: ")
    self.label2.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky=W)
    self.labelMessage = Label(self, text=guessedWord + guessedWrong)
    self.labelMessage.grid(row=2, column=2)

    self.label3 = Label(self, text="Guessed Letters: ")
    self.label3.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky=W)
    self.lblGuessed = Label(self, text=guessedWord)
    self.lblGuessed.grid(row=3, column=2)

    self.label4 = Label(self, text="Lives left: ")
    self.label4.grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky=W)
    self.lblLives = Label(self, text=lives)
    self.lblLives.grid(row=4, column=2)

    def checkWord():
        while True:
            out = ""
            for letter in randomWords:
                if letter in guessedWord:
                    self.labelGuessResult.config(text=out+letter)
                else:
                    self.labelGuessResult.config(text=out+" _")
            if out == randomWords:
                self.labelMessage.config("You have guesed the ", randomWords)
                break
            if guess in guessedWord:
                self.labelMessage.config(text="already guessed that!")
            elif guess in randomWords:
                self.labelMessage.config(text="correct!")
                guessedWord.append(guess)
            else:
                self.labelMessage.config(text="Wrong!")
                guessedWrong.append(guess)
            print()

    '''BUTTON GUESS'''
    self.submitBTN = Button(self, text="Guess", command=checkWord)
    self.submitBTN.grid(row=1,column=4)


frames = Tk()              #creates the frame
frames.geometry("500x450") #sets frame size
app = window(frames)       #calls and runs the frame within the class
frames.mainloop()          #runs the frame continuously
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one major problem is the `checkWord()` function. The first time you call this function it starts a loop that I have difficulty in understanding and which doesn't seem to end.

This means that once you call `checkWord()` you'll not be able to input more letters to the entry.

My suggestion is for you to first make a flowchart of the guessing and checking procedure and then implement it bit by bit while checking that you get the correct return. To begin with it may be simpler to skip the GUI because it just adds complexity until you get it to work.